# How to avoid coupling when using useReducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

To prevent passing callbacks to child components I am using `useReducer` instead.  This avoids the issue of child components re-rendering on each parent render but the downside seems to be a tight coupling between parent and child.  By tight coupling, I mean that the child needs to be explicitly aware of the shape of the action expected by the reducer which is defined by the parent.

Imagine, for example, a date picker component.  At some point this component needs to pass the new date/time value to the calling component so that the data can be saved (or somehow used).  With callbacks, we can have a simple prop like `saveDate={onSaveDate}`.  The date picker defines the contract by saying "I expect these props".  Specifically, I expect a `saveDate` prop with signature of `newDate => {}`.  This flow makes sense to me.

With `useReducer`, the parent passes `dispatch` to the date picker, and the date picker needs to be aware of how to create an action that matches what the reducer expects.  This can be solved by defining action creators in a module somewhere and importing them into the date picker but this feels backwards to me.  If the date picker will be called from various components in the application, all the components will need to agree on the this interface - the shape of the action.  This seems to couple not only one component with the date picker, but all components that use the date picker with each other.

So, what am I overlooking and what strategy exists to deal with this?  For what it's worth, I went back to using callbacks where cleaner code makes more sense than the performance concern of re-rendering.

Comment: in redux, isn't this handled by creating action types? a common set of string constants that you use to label actions and events. i'm not sure if that's the solution you're looking for, but it'd be a place to look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest currying dispatch with the action type in the parent component, like so:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(datepickerReducer, initialState)

  // might wanna useCallback here if your DatePicker is pure
  const changeDate = newDate => dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_DATE', newDate })

  return <DatePicker onChange={changedate} value={state} />
}
```

This way your component stays isolated from the rest and you can use it as you did before hooks. Although, if you are using the datepickerReducer often, it will be annoying to re-define changeDate every time, so I would have a custom hook do it:

```js
const useDatepicker = init => {
  const [date, dispatch] = useReducer(datepickerReducer)
  const changeDate = useCallback(newDate => dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_DATE', newDate }), [])

  // I prefer using an object, makes it more convenient to reach values that would have been at the end of the array
  return { date, changeDate, /* You could have resetDate here aswell */ }
}

// USAGE
const { date, changeDate } = useDatepicker(new Date())
```

Comment: The approach you proposed brings us back to the original problem which is re-rendering of the child component (datepicker in this case) whenever the parent component renders.  This happens because the changeDate function is recreated on each render. Makes me wonder if we can get around this by storing changeDate in state.

Comment: If you check the first block of code, I'm suggesting you to use `useCallback`. It does exactly what you need, it prevents the function from being recreated, and allows you to pass it to pure components. I updated the second block of code with it, so you can see. Here is the doc https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: ok.  I see that now.  I missed the comment when I first look through the code snippet.